# Product sum with dynamic sheet names in formula

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, formula

We have a macro that loops through a set of 50 workbooks that have different amounts of sheets. The sheets look similar but all have different sheet names.

We want to place a formula in the first sheet ("Framsida") that searches through column B in sheet 3 to the last sheet to identify how many unique entries there are.

We have been working with PRODUCTSUM and FREQUENCY.
The formula works when pasted into the sheet manually.
When trying this with the macro, it starts linking to other data sources with the error message

> "This workbook contains links to other data sources".

The code we tried:

```vb
Worksheets("Framsida").Range("m5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(''" & Sheets(3).Name & " : " & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & " '!$B$6:$b$200, ' " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name & " : " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & " '!$B$6:$b$200)<>0))"
```

This is the result that comes out in sheet "Framsida" when running the macro:

```
=PRODUKTSUMMA(--(FREKVENS('8007029 :[ 8007062 ] 8007062 '!$B$6:$B$200; '8007029 :[ 8007062 ] 8007062 '!$B$6:$B$200)<>0))
```

Where PRODUKTSUMMA=PRODUCTSUM
and   FREKVENS=FREQUENCY

It adds the last sheet name in square brackets and we have no idea why. We are open for suggestions to other solutions.

This is the entire loop:

```vb
Sub SummeringFramsida()

'Variabler för loopen
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Filepath As String

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

'Öppnar filer tills det att man kommer till Huvudfilen i listan, filerna som ska sökas måste alltså ligga ovanför i listan'
Filepath = "C:\Users\JohannaFalkenstrand\Desktop\Excelfix\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "Huvudfil.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Workbooks(MyFile).Activate

    Worksheets("Framsida").Range("m5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY('" & Sheets(3).Name & " : " & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & " '!$B$6:$b$200, ' " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name & " : " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & " '!$B$6:$b$200)<>0))"

    'Stänger, sparar och går till nästa fil'
    Workbooks(MyFile).Save
    Workbooks(MyFile).Close
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: at first look, it looks like you need to make reference to the right workbook in each loop. I mean, when you do `Sheets(3).Name` it will take the 3rd sheet of the **active** workbook (and that one may not be the one you want in the loop). I think you should post the code of how you loop trough those 50 workbooks (just the relevant parts of code).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I just posted the code for the loop as an answer below. We have cleaned up the code and removed the parts that are irrelevant for this problem

Comment: Within the loop, the code activates the workbooks and closes it down after entering the code. Therfore, it has only one workbook (activeworkbook) open at a time

Comment: Please, do not post the code as an answer. You can edit your original question and update it. Please, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Okay, just updated the original post

Comment: When calling a formula through multiple sheets but same cells, it can be done like `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1:A2)`. In your code I see blanks and `'` and they are not needed (unless you select them individually). Maybe something like `Worksheets("Framsida").Range("m5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(" & Sheets(3).Name & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "!$B$6:$b$200," & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name & ":" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "!$B$6:$b$200)<>0))"`

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with `Range(...).Address(1,1,xlA1,1)`. This will give you a string of range reference that contains both the workbook and the sheet reference. Then you can compile the required formula with simple string manipulation, like

```
For Each wb in <SomeCollectionOfWorkbooks>
    For Each sh in wb.Sheets
        Debug.Print "Copy this to the required cell = SUM(" & _
             sh.Range("B6:B200").Address(1,1,xlA1,1) & ")"
    Next
Next
```

The key is the `external reference` parameter of `.Address`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer us. We found another solution that worked, we would definatly try to learn more about the range.adress, it seems useful :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use same range but on different sheets at same time, so you need to check this out:

> [Create a reference to the same cell range on multiple
> worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f)

Applying this to your code this should kind of work:

```
Worksheets("Framsida").Range("m5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(" & Sheets(3).Name & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "!$B$6:$b$200," & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name & ":" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "!$B$6:$b$200)<>0))"
```